# Xcode 12 issue - Could not find module 'FrameworkName' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12

After updating to Xcode 12 the project gives me this error when building on simulator:

```
Could not find module 'FrameworkName' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64
```

The framework is installed with cocoapods.
It works with Xcode 11. Building on "Any iOS Device" or real iPhone with Xcode 12 also works just fine.
What's different in Xcode 12?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I fixed this by ensuring the build setting `VALID_ARCHS` (now appearing at the bottom of Build Settings in Xcode 12) contains "`x86_64`".

That is:

- Before I had: `VALID_ARCHS = arm64, arm64e`
- After fixing: `VALID_ARCHS = arm64, arm64e, x86_64`

(A little counterintuitive, as the error message says it couldn't find the module for `arm64`-apple-ios-simulator, :shrug:)

Comment: Wow this actually fixed the issue! It finally runs successfully on simulator. Thanks!

Comment: This one works, I tried replacing the value of `VALID_ARCHS` by what is given here: `arm64, arm64e, x86_64`

Comment: `VALID_ARCHS` is no longer here in Xcode 12.3.

Comment: @aheze yes it's been "missing" since before 12.3 actually. But you can just add it yourself to the `User-Defined` section at the bottom of Build Settings.

Comment: It's indeed misleading because of the `arm64` part, but the iOS Simulator actually runs natively on x86-64 (on Intel Macs), so the solution makes perfect sense. This is why it's a _simulator_, not an _emulator_. It's also why it's *incredibly* faster than Android emulators. Apple Silicon Macs also run it natively, but now on arm64, the same arch as iPhones and other Apple products. Maybe the error came to be this way because the simulator was renamed for the Apple Silicon transition. I don't have any insider information, just speculating.

Comment: Xcode 12.5.1 - I don't see VALID_ARCHS in Build Settings

Comment: To add it yourself as a user defined setting, click on the + icon at the top (to the right of Levels)

Comment: This solution should be added to the client app target.
If you are unable to find the VALID_ARCHS on Build settings, just add the User-Defined build setting by
'Editor -> Add Build Settings -> Add User-Defined Setting'

Comment: this is the solution I was looking for. worked like a charm. thanks very much @Mete

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, helpful!

Answer (score 4):

This situation presumably arises when you modify your project to suit the new M1 Macs, and then try to run the same project on an Intel Mac.

It basically tries to run on the ARM architecture and finds X86_64 instead.

To resolve the problem you just need to restrict the build operation to the active (X86_64) architecture only.

You can do this by setting Build Active Architectures only to YES.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by excluding arm64 in both app Target and test Target for Debug like the below pictures.

Tested and worked on Xcode 13.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This resolved my issue. I didn't set the test project and it kept failing on XCode cloud.

Answer (score 3):

Got this error on our app for library and this solved my problem:

close XCode

open Finder app and show there "Applications"

right click on icon Xcode and click on "Get info" (or something similar)

there is checkbox "Open with Rosseta" (or something similar). Select it

run Xcode again and try to build

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123614?login=true

Comment: this works ESPECIALLY well if you installed the Ruby extension called "ffi" (sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi) onto your machine, but it will not work unless you include the Rosetta mentioned above.  To activate ffi you will also need to run "arch -x86_64 pod install" into your project folder.  This should help you with iOS simulator problems on your M1 machines if running a pre-M1 project.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Similar to the comment above, I had a local Swift Package developed pre-M1 and it would only work for physical devices, not simulators.

Answer (score 2):

For M1 Chip Based Mac Follow the instructions below..

> Applications > Xcode > Get Info> checked "Open using Rosetta"

Thats's it and you are good to go.

Tested in Xcode 13.3.1, Apple M1 Pro

Comment: In XCode 15 you need to allow Product --> Destinations --> "Show all Run Destinations" and select a (Rosetta) iOS Simulator.

This is required for Apple Silicon Macs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` for `VALID_ARCHS` for Debug for Any iOS Simulator SDK and set `YES` for `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` for Debug. It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Current Working Solution**

```
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Could you explain where we should add these lines ?

Comment: This is added to the Podfile?

Answer (score -2):

In the newest version of Xcode, (Xcode 13.2) the option for `VALID_ARCHS` is no longer available. So i made the decision to switch the test device from a simulator to a physical device, in Xcode. I did not have the issue when running on a physical test device

Answer (score -4):

You can try delete derived data of your app and then clean and build app, you can follow the steps of the following link https://programmingwithswift.com/delete-derived-data-xcode/

Comment: I've already tried removing derived data, clean build, restarting the Xcode, restarting the Mac.. Nothing helps

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: Try Mete's solution.