# Could not find module 'MapboxDirections' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: i386, x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64

Tags: ios, flutter, mapbox, apple-silicon

I am working on a Flutter application which makes use of the following package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation

While running this for iOS 15.2 Simulator I am getting the following error:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not find module 'MapboxDirections' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: i386, x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64, i386-apple-ios-simulator, at: /Users/absatyaprakash/Projects/one-stop-2021/app/one_stop/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/MapboxDirections/MapboxDirections.framework/Modules/MapboxDirections.swiftmodule
/Users/absatyaprakash/Projects/one-stop-2021/app/one_stop/ios/Pods/MapboxNavigation/Sources/MapboxNavigation/Array.swift:0:7
```

I am using an Apple Silicon MacBook. Initially, I was facing the issue described here - [Xcode 12, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-12-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-io), but after excluding the arm64 architecture from the Build Settings, and adding the following to my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

I am not getting this anymore. Now I am stuck at the above mentioned issue. I have tried numerous solutions (including the one here - [could not find module 'Alamofire' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561337/could-not-find-module-alamofire-for-target-arm64-apple-ios-simulator-found)) since the last 2 days, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Similar issue here - https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/issues/148

Comment: known issue, no fixed solution yet, I ended up upgrading all libraries and changing a few build settings. unfortunately on client machine if failed. i had to made a few more changes.

Comment: Did it work finally after the changes?

Comment: yes but different changes for different machines.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit about those changes? It might be useful for me.

Comment: I am not sure, I work on native. You can try two things - `Build Configuration` is set to `Release` for your project active `scheme` and `Build Active Architectures Only` is `Yes` in `Build Settings` for your target. You are flutter, this might mess with other flutter dependencies.

Comment: you can search both changes here on stackoverflow, there are lots of answers available with steps.

Comment: I had actually modified these before asking the question, since some answers were suggesting this. No results still though.

Comment: For M1 Chip Based Mac follow this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72257205/5575548)